# how to set my height to 100% with a dynamic table inside?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

I have a `div` with a table inside. This div has a background color `black`

Now I make a AJAX request and get some data which I append to the table:

```
$("#MyTable").append('<tr><td>' + value.myText + '</td></tr>');
```

Now I'm facind the problem, that the table gets longer than the background. How can I say something like:

Make the parent div as long as it must be to be behind the whole table?

Comment: Seeing as you've clearly stated this as a HTML/CSS problem, could we see some HTML/CSS code?

Comment: And please make it a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of the parent div to `auto`. Now the parent will get short and big according to the table height.

Or if you want it to be of height `100%` then first you will need to set all of its parent containers height to `100%` then of this parent. So like if this is the outer most parent then this could be your applied CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }   /*THE MOST OUTER PARENT*/
parent { height: 100%; }       /*THE SECOND MOST OUTER PARENT*/
parent table { height: 100%; } /*THE TABLE*/
```

Comment: That is not necessarily true, especially if the div is floating.

Comment: @Anpan that's why I gave him another solution.